# Sharing internet on Kitkat 4.4.2

Tags: tethering, usb-tethering

Presently i am using dual sim card (Grameen phone and Bangla Link) network in phone internet purpose, I have purchase internet package of 4GB data. Now I want to use this sim card internet 4GB data to my pc windows. My android phone verson is 4.4.2, So how can use this 4 GB data pack in computer. Please send me the procedure of using internet through USB cable (between phone sim net to computer).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using internet through usb, you can also try using internet on your PC by connecting your phone to PC via bluetooth. I haven't tried accessing internet using usb cable, but the bluetooth method works fine.